# Best options for tilt shift macrophotography

Tags: macro, macro-lenses, medium-format, bellows

I'm considering few options to do macrophotography with tilt shift possibilities.
I'll have a Canon R5C or R3 camera and either:

- Canon EF 50 and 90 TSE with EF-R adapter and [Novoflex R bellow](https://www.novoflex.de/en/products-637/macro/extension-bellows.html) without tilt shift movements

or

- Novoflex tilt shift bellow with medium format lenses (eg., Fujifilm, Schneider Kreuznach), so I can have proper image circle

What would be significantly better in terms of possibilities (eg., with medium format lenses, I have more many lenses, even zoom, with the Canon TS-E, I can rotate both tilt and shift, but not with the tilt shift bellow) and image quality (say I'm using 50 Mpixels) ?

I would like to optimize image quality and tilt and shift and macro possibilities (magnitude).

A drawback with the medium format would be the price, depending on the optics.

Comment: Any Canon TS-E lens will project a significantly larger image circle than a standard EF lens. They have to in order to allow for the shift movements of the TS-E lens.

Answer (score 2):

A tilt shift lens like the Canon TSE and a medium format lens on a tilt shift bellows both provide oversized image circles to allow shifting the lens/circle... so I do not see an advantage to the medium format lenses in the sense of "a proper image circle."

FWIW, I have both. I have the older Novaflex TS bellows (square, only the front standard moves), and I have Nikon PC-E lenses. Due to the small format of DSLR's, I find the tilt function of both to be quite difficult to use with any accuracy; even when tethered to a laptop it is difficult (but that does help a lot). And that's only for general use/closeup use (small-ish product shots)... I haven't even attempted macro where accurate use of TS would be that much more difficult. IMO, you would be better off using the R3's built in focus stacking 99% of the time.

IMO, the main advantage of the bellows is that it allows a large variety of lens options and magnification ratios for macro and high magnification macro (reversed lens), which is how I use it. For critical alignment I use a geared head, not the tilt lens/bellows function.

Answer (score 1):

Large format film cameras probably provide the best option for macro photography because:

- The maximum magnification is only dependent on bellows extension.
- Any focal length lens can be used.
- The image circle becomes larger as the magnification increases.
- The longer focal lengths make for larger absolute tilt movements because the film plane and lens plane are further apart, and the greater absolute tilt movement allows for finer adjustments.
- The longer focal lengths allow for greater working distances.
- Large format film provides unparalleled resolution.
- Focusing with the rear standard allows the lens to subject distance to remain constant.

Of course there’s no such thing as a free lunch.

But large format film is also easy to reason about, and allows for multiple exposure lighting.